# How to fix "ERROR 1: Cannot get geotransform" in GDAL

Tags: gdal, geotiff

I am trying to read values from a geoTiff and am using gdallocationinfo for that purpose.

However, when I try to do that, e.g with `gdallocationinfo out.tif -wgs85 8.5 47.3`, the following error occurs:

```
root@bc21abca5e07:/usr/src/app# gdallocationinfo out.tif -wgs84 8.5 47.3
ERROR 1: Cannot get geotransform
```

Note: if I leave the `-wgs84` option away, I am able to read the values from the .tif. Also, the `-geoloc` function is resulting in the same output as `-wgs84`.

Is this a problem with the geoTiff? I have already tried this command on Windows and on Debian, resulting in the same output both times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "fix it" short of properly georeferencing your dataset.

The error means that your dataset lacks georeferencing information so GDAL is unable to convert the WGS84 coordinates to pixel coordinates.